# How to access a assigned value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary here:

```
this_dict = {
  "Flamingo" : 1,
  "Eagle" : 2,
  "Cockatoo" : 3,
}
```

And I want the user to enter a number and see if it's in the dictionary. And when he/she enters the number I want the program to say "you have chosen name of the bird". For example, if the user enters 2, I want the program to output "you have chosen Eagle" and say the user enters 5, I want the program to say "No category found for your number" and return the code to the beginning where it asks the same question as before. I have tried using the code below but it keeps coming with the wrong answer. Can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

My code so far:

```
print('Flamingo = 1, Eagle = 2, Cockatoo = 3') 
user = input('What bird would you like? Please enter the number. ')
if user in this_dict: 
    pass 
elif user not in this_dict:
    print('No bird found')
```

This is what happens when I enter `2`

```
Flamingo = 1, Eagle = 2, Cockatoo = 3
What bird would you like? Please enter the number. 2
```

After this, I tried entering the numbers between 0 and 99 using this code to see what would happen.

```
for x in range(100):
    user = x
    if user in this_dict:
        pass
    elif user not in this_dict:
        print(f'Testing {x}: No bird found')
```

The result was:

```
Testing 0: No bird found
Testing 1: No bird found
Testing 2: No bird found
Testing 3: No bird found
Testing 4: No bird found
Testing 5: No bird found
Testing 6: No bird found
Testing 7: No bird found
Testing 8: No bird found
Testing 9: No bird found
Testing 10: No bird found
...
Testing 98: No bird found
Testing 99: No bird found
```

As you can see, there is an error with my code and I don't know how to fix it. Please tell me where the error is and what needs to be changed.

Comment: Keep a reverse dictionary for a fast check.

Comment: *What* keeps coming with the wrong answer? Give a [mre].

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far that is not working out? You access dictionary values using e.g. `this_dict["Eagle"]`, and check if a value is in a dictionary like `"Eagle" in this_dict`

Comment: I use the following
`print('Flamingo = 1, Eagle = 2, Cockatoo = 3')
user   = input('What bird would you like? Please enter the number. ')

if user in this_dict:
  pass
elif user not in this_dict:
  print('No bird found')`

And it just skips to the elif.

Answer (score 3):

Is it not better to construct the dict in the revers order? Then the value is simply the key for the category?

```
this_dict_reverse = {
  1 : "Flamingo",
  2 : "Eagle",
  3 : "Cockatoo",
}
```

You can have both the reverse and original dict in the program and the problem with error key entery can be solved using try and except:

```
try:
    print(this_dict_reverse[5])
except KeyError:
    print("No category found for your number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Each item in a dictionary is always a key-value pair, and when you check for membership you are looking for a specific key-value pair being in the dictionary and not the key or the value alone.

To do what you are attempting to do, try this instead:

```
if n not in this_dict.values():
    ...
```

Comment: I have already tried that.

Comment: And what was the result?